# Creating Navigation Bar programmatically with storyboard

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
    UINavigationController *navVC = [UINavigationController new];
    ViewController *VC1 = [ViewController new];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [navVC setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:VC1] animated:NO];

    [window setRootViewController:navVC];

    return window;
}
```

When calling this method, I get my Nav Bar but I don't see what i have in my ViewController view in the storyboard. I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong though, i've tried adding subview and stuff but nothing works out. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to write this code instead of what you have written

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

self. window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
UINavigationController *navVC = [UINavigationController new];
UIStoryboard *mStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"your storyboard name" bundle:nil];

ViewController *VC1 = [mStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC"];


[navVC setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:VC1] animated:NO];
[self. window setRootViewController:navVC];

 [self. window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

Comment: Thanks! Now i got the problem of adding a subview. I have three different views, one subview works fine but when i try to display the third subview it loads the right navbar so it says 'Screen Three' though the screen below is the same as before.

Comment: can u tell me how you are adding view ?? on tapping any button?? or someway else?? please Mention the code

Comment: I add the views with [VC2.view addSubview:VC3.view];
            [navVC.view addSubview:VC2.view];

Comment: Doing this once works fine but when i add both as subviews it'll only display vc2 even though the navigation bar changes correctly

Comment: I meant [windows addSubview:VC2.view]; not [navVC.view ...]

Comment: actually navVC.view is consisting its own navigation bar in its view. so when you are using [navVC.view addSubview:VC2.view] , final view is overlapping the whole view of navVC.

Comment: [windows addSubview:VC2.view]; its only add a view on window. but first screen which you are seeing thats a rootView , dat is        [self. window setRootViewController:navVC];

Comment: I don't know why i wrote this code, i actually meant [windows addSubview:VC2.view]; but that still won't work. Using this shows me the third view for the second and third page instead of showing the second view for the second page

Comment: please be specific what do you want?

Comment: How do i add these view controllers to the navigation controller stack? i understand the idea but i don't know how to write the code and i haven't found anything on the internet. I've tried addChildViewController but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: [navVC setViewControllers:@[VC1,VC2]animated:NO]; just write this code

Comment: look at the ans which i have posted now

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

{

```
self. window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];

UINavigationController *navVC = [UINavigationController new];
navVC.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UIStoryboard *mStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

ViewController *VC1 = [mStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC"];




 FirstViewController *VC2 = [mStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First"];
SecondViewController *VC3 = [mStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];

[VC2.view addSubview:VC3.view];
 [navVC setViewControllers:@[VC1,VC2]animated:NO];

[self. window setRootViewController:navVC];

 [self. window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

Comment: Now when i run the app it opens with displaying the second view with a green background instead of the first view, and when i go to the third the background turns black instead of red, when i go to the second one it stays black instead of turning green and the first one works fine and the background is blue